# Apply different function to each element in list?

Tags: list, time-date, mapping

I have a time-stamp of a video formatted as "00:00:00,000" such that "%H:%M:%s,%3N".

I am want to eventually use this timestamp as part of an `in-interval-p` function where I take two timestamps and a current timestamp and check if I'm currently between the two. The best idea I have is to convert these timestamps to cumulative seconds.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but here is what I currently have

```
(require 'dash)
(require 's)

(defvar time-stamp "00:00:52,010")

(s-split "[:|,]" time-stamp)
;; ("00" "00" "52" "010")
```

What I would like to do, but not sure how, is something like

```
(map '((lambda (x) (* x 3600.0))
       (lambda (x) (* x 60.0))
       (lambda (x) (x))
       (lambda (x) (/ (float x) 1000.0))) 
  (s-split "[:|,]" time-stamp))

;; (0.0 0.0 52 0.01)
```

Is it possible to apply a different function at each index of a list? I would then sum the list to get `52.01` seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function in the "dash" library you are using.

```el
(-zip-with #'funcall
           '((lambda (x) (* x 3600.0))
             (lambda (x) (* x 60.0))
             (lambda (x) x)
             (lambda (x) (/ (float x) 1000.0)))
           (mapcar #'string-to-number (s-split "[:|,]" time-stamp)))
```

Note that `s-split` returns *strings* but you want to work with *numbers*, so you can use `string-to-number` for that.

Comment: Note: your 4 quoted lambdas can't be compiled (and can't use lexical scoping).  Better construct your list with `list` or with ``..`(..,(lambda ..) ,(lambda ..) ..)..``

Comment: You can also use `cl-mapcar` from `cl-lib` instead of `-zip-with`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you've overcomplicated the problem.

You're obtaining a list comprising hours, minutes, seconds, and microseconds, so I think your code would be simpler and more readable if you expressed that explicitly:

```el
(require 'cl-lib)

(defvar time-stamp "00:00:52,010")

(cl-destructuring-bind (hours minutes seconds microseconds)
    (mapcar #'string-to-number (split-string time-stamp "[:,]"))
  (+ (* hours 3600)
     (* minutes 60)
     seconds
     (/ (float microseconds) 1000.0)))
```